# How to extract non-overlapping ranges of field 'region' using R?

Tags: r

Given a file:

The three columns are: ID, region left and region right.

```
region1 1 100
region2 20 120
region3 101 200
region4 220 280
```

How could I only extract the regions which are not overlapped?
To get:

```
region1 1 100
region3 101 200
region4 220 280
```

Comment: See, e.g. http://web.mit.edu/r_v3.0.1/lib/R/library/IRanges/html/IntervalTree-class.html.

Comment: Do you mean remove the minimum number of regions so that there are no overlaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution that uses a loop to compare each row/range with the previous one and uses a function to spot overlaps.

```
# example dataset
dt = data.frame(region = 1:4,
                min = c(1,20,101,220),
                max = c(100,120,200,280))

# order data based on minimum value of range (in case you don't have an order already)
dt = dt[order(dt$min),]

dt

# region min max
# 1      1   1 100
# 2      2  20 120
# 3      3 101 200
# 4      4 220 280


# function that spots overlap
overlap = function(x,y) {

  res = ifelse(x[2] >= y[1],1,0)
  return(res)
}


# set starting point (row)
i = 2

# a loop that compares each row with the previous one and deletes row when it finds overlap
while(i <= nrow(dt)){

dt_temp = dt

if (overlap(dt_temp[i-1,2:3], dt_temp[i,2:3]) == 1) {dt_temp[i,]=NA; dt = dt_temp[complete.cases(dt_temp),]} else {dt = dt_temp; i = i+1}

}

dt

# region min max
# 1      1   1 100
# 3      3 101 200
# 4      4 220 280
```

Note that this process depends on the first (fixed) range to calculate the overlaps. So, if you have the ranges [1, 100], [5,10], [15,30], [32,60] it will return only the [1,100] as all the rest overlap with it.